# Same Color Code, Different Effect on Different Monitors

Tags: css, colors

I find it strange that the same color code (ex:#FEE9CC) results in different representations depending on the user's monitor. My computer is connected with two monitors, and I found this behavior. I guess there are some colors whose representations fluctuate. Then, what are the colors that always represent the same way? In other words,

**how do I make sure that "brown" on my computer is actually brown on others'?**

Here's the color that I used. It is shown as light brown on one monitor, and light pink on the other.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can't. Even if your users wouldn't fiddle with any of the hardware color settings on purpose, a vast majority of them is not going to have the correct [color profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management) for their monitor set up (and almost nobody besides designers is going to have a [calibrated monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_calibration) anyway).

If you were doing print work (photo retouching, pre-press, …), this would be an important issue, and the tools you would be working with would provide extensive functionality for color management, previewing how colors look on another medium (proofing), and so on. Web browsers and file formats, on the other hand, simply were never designed for accurate rendition of colors.

Answer (score 1):

Sort answer but You Can't.

You and your computer can use the right color codes for a correctly calibrated monitor but monitor don't 'send' feedback as to their roles and how they're bring presented.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Monitors and graphics cards can be configured in many different ways. Some like "warmer" color tones, some like them "colder".

If I wanted I could set up my monitor to show only grays. If you choose red, it will be gray for me, if you choose green, it will be gray too.